# I can't group all elements (NONE LOCKED) when adapting A4 to A3 in Indesign CS 6

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm resizing and have changed the doc setup to be A3 from A4. I then selected all elements (none locked) and grouped them.

Then, when attempting to hold shift and drag them to fill the page, two images do not move in place with everything else.

They stay where they were .

In addition to that, the selection outline goes right down past the page to where my mouse can't control the bottom end once I've released the dotted selection box after dragging it.

This means I have to move it up to find the bottom of the selection outline again, but even then, it does not allow me to move it back closer to its actual contents, it just squashes the contents. Am I missing something.

Sorry I'm trying to get something print ready for a client and this is a bit challenging. I will be online to answer questions you may have. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1) Are your two images on a master page? on a locked layer?

2) if the "selection outline goes down past the page," then it sounds like you have some tremendously huge image (the outer border) which is somehow cropped or masked to display the bit you can see (the inside border). You can't move it because it's so large that "the transformation will make it fall off the page," as Illustrator used to whine.

For messes like this, I usually copy everything I can to a new document and try to start fresh. If you can't copy the two immovable objects, try re-importing them into a new A3 document and see if they behave themselves there.